# TCP connection thread for reading and writing and receiving event messages in java

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, client

I'm new to Java and TCP in general.

I have the following scenario where I send a request to a tcp server and I receive a reply directly, then the server will send an unsolicited event message later.

I implemented the following Client

```
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.net.Inet4Address;
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.SocketException;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;

 import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
 import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
 import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

 public class TcpClient {

private InetAddress connectedAddress;
private Socket tcpSocket;
private int connectedPort;
private OutputStream outStream;
private boolean first = true;

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TcpClient.class);

public TcpClient(String host, int port) {
    try {
        this.connectedAddress = Inet4Address.getByName(host);
        this.connectedPort = port;
        this.tcpSocket = new Socket(connectedAddress, connectedPort);
        this.outStream = this.tcpSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    log.debug("Sending Message \n" + message);
    synchronized (this) {
        if (!this.tcpSocket.isConnected())
            return;
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outStream);
        dos.write(message.getBytes());
        dos.flush();
        if(first){
            first = false;
            (new Thread(new TcpListeningThread())).start();
        }
    }
}

private class TcpListeningThread implements Runnable {

    public TcpListeningThread() {
        // Nothing to do...
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                DataInputStream dis = new   DataInputStream(tcpSocket.getInputStream());
                int len = dis.readInt();
                byte[] data = new byte[len];
                dis.read(data);
                String response = new String(data, "US-ASCII");
                if (null != response && !StringUtils.isBlank(response)) {
                log.debug("Received Response [" + response + "]");
                processXmlResponse(response);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }

}
```

This code seems only to read the first response for the first request sent while removing the if(first) condition and calling the reading thread every time a request is sent, 
and removing the while true, the code seems to be able to read the response for every request sent, but of course won't be able to read the event messages.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks :)

Comment: You certainly should _not_ be recreating the `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` on every transaction.  But on looking at the code, that doesn't seem to be a bug -- just a bad pattern.

Comment: And you are sure that a) the entire first message is received and b) the server has sent the 2nd message?